# How to change FMX ListView header background color?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

In a multi-device FMX project, I am trying to change the background colour of a ListView.

There is a StyleBook placed on the Form. I edit a custom Style for the ListView, changing the background color, say to clRed. Then I close the editor, apply the style, and run the app. The ListView's backgound color is still White.

So, I changed the ItemBackground to clRed, then run the app. This time, the item background is indeed Red, but the header backgound color is still White.

So, back in the style editor, I add a rectangle to the header (aligned with Client) and filled with clRed. Apply the style and run the app. It doesn't work.

Then I tried to edit the header's SourceLink, changed the colour in their template (only some Blues are available), then apply the style. It works at design-time, but not at run-time. The running app's header is still White.

Such trivial things, Embarcadero cannot solve properly. I really hate that I dived into this FMX too much. Now, it is too late to change to another RAD solution. I have no idea if anyone can help me with this.

Also, the fonts in Delphi 11.1's editor cannot be changed. I altered the font's size, but it will change back to the old size when restarted. The DataModule window won't hold the positions of DB icons properly. If I move an icon, and save it, the icon will change position, and all icons are overlapped with each other. I am not sure if this is only me or a general issue.

Comment: Sounds like issues you need to take up with Embarcadero directly, by [filing bug reports](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: You say that you changed the colour to `clRed`.  This is a `TColor` colour, whereas FMX uses `TAlphaColor`, i.e. with an alpha component.  If you do somehow apply `clRed` to the background (although I don't know how you can), then the list would still appear white as the background is totally clear, i.e. no colour, just as if you'd set Opacity to 0.
In 10.4 I can set the background of the style to `Red` and an empty list shows in red (I haven't tried with items in the list).
But you say that `clRed` works with the item background, so perhaps you're not actually using a `TColor` colour.

Comment: @Philip J. Rayment The LV background colr is selected by propery editor. I just used clRed representing color red, not real coding. Similarly you can set the itembackground color to what you wanted in the property editor. Strangely, only Itembackgroundcolor works. Nothing else do the job.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure.  But as I said, it seemed to work for me, but with the previous version, so perhaps this is a regression that needs reporting as suggested.

Comment: thanks all. Already report it as suggested https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38407?filter=17608 . In fact, the LV bg-color can be set. I tried in 11.1. However, when the LV filled with many data. The items bg-colour and header bg-color are the ones I want to change. Now I can only change Items color, the header bg-colour still in white. Looks very odd.